# numpy multidimensional indexing :use np array and list give different results

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

why b1 b2 give different result, but b0 ,b1,b3 give the same. and get an
"FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result."

```
a = np.array([[6, 7], [8, 9]])
print(a.shape)
print(a)
print()

b0 = a[[0, 0]]
print('b0')
print(b0.shape)
print(b0)
print()

b1 = a[[[0, 0]]]
print('b1')
print(b1.shape)
print(b1)
print()

b2 = a[np.array([[0, 0]])]
print('b2')
print(b2.shape)
print(b2)
print()

b3= a[np.array([0, 0])]
print('b3')
print(b3.shape)
print(b3)
```

(2, 2)
[[6 7]
 [8 9]]

b0
(2, 2)
[[6 7]
 [6 7]]

b1
(2, 2)
[[6 7]
 [6 7]]

b2
(1, 2, 2)
[[[6 7]
  [6 7]]]

b3
(2, 2)
[[6 7]
 [6 7]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of history

```
b1 = a[[[0, 0]]]
```

was/is evaluated as

```
b1 = a[([0, 0],)]
b1 = a[[0, 0]]
```

The warning is telling us that this anomaly is being corrected.

Indexing like `a[i,j]` is really `a[(i,j)]`, passing a tuple to the `getitem` method.  Due to mergers of various packages way in past, under some circumstances a list was interpreted in the same way.  You found one.

The futurewarning is telling us that the cleanest, clearest way of doing advanced indexing is with tuples and arrays.  There was, and to an extent still is, an ambiguity when using lists.

This is described in the 1.15.0 release notes deprecations,

```
Multidimensional indexing with anything but a tuple is deprecated. This means that 
the index list in ind = [slice(None), 0]; arr[ind] should be changed to a tuple, 
e.g., ind = [slice(None), 0]; arr[tuple(ind)] or arr[(slice(None), 0)]. 
That change is necessary to avoid ambiguity in expressions such as 
arr[[[0, 1], [0, 1]]],  interpreted as arr[array([0, 1]), array([0, 1])], 
that will be interpreted as arr[array([[0, 1], [0, 1]])] in the future.
```

So in the future b1 will behave like b2, but for now it is like b0.

Comment: thanks for the useful answer, but why a[[0, 0]] will not be interpreted as a[(0, 0)]?

Comment: Since the interpretation lies in compiled code, I can't say exactly why.  As the note indicates there was some ambiguity inherited from previous packages (e.g. `numeric`), that they are trying to cleanup.  But deprecation is a slow process.  Unless you are trying to understand old code, there's little value in deciphering these old patterns.